# Pandas Dataframe read_csv fails to start correctly

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

'''pip install --upgrade pandas==0.25.0'''

After running this code, I received an error when I used read_csv. I think that something wrong happened to the packages. Do I have to re-install or is there an easier way to solve this issue?

[Pandas Screenshot from Notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lf6P.png)

Code is: '''df_complete=pd.read_csv('tmdb-movies.csv')'''

Error says: TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_rows'

Comment: Don't paste images of code, paste the code as text in your question instead (and format it as code). This is for two reasons; first of all it makes it searchable, if somebody else have the same issue and search for it the error, they will not be able to find your question if you have your error as an image. Secondly, what happens if the Webpage where you host your image dissapears/remove your image? I'll tell you what happens, nobody will be able to understand your question in the future.

Comment: You are getting an output which seems ok. The error is coming from format which occurs apparently while displaying the dataframe as html. Do you mind restarting your notebook and rerunning just the required cells (import + read_csv) ?

Comment: It didn't work.